# How can soft managed package dependencies be handled in packaging 2?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, packaging-2

We have a managed package under development that makes significant use of dynamic SOQL and the map-like methods of SObject so the package can work with multiple "other" managed packages, and those other packages can be present in various combinations.

We were planning to use packaging 2, but it does not look possible to incorporate "other" managed packages in the `sfdx force:package:create` without introducing a hard dependency, meaning the resulting package can't be installed unless all the "other" packages are installed which is not what we need.

The problem is very much in the area of code coverage. Our Continuous Integration (CI) build hits 90% test coverage with the "other" packages installed and the tests still pass with no "other" packages installed but with code coverage of way less than 75%.

When we use packaging 2 without the "other" managed packages, that "way less than 75%" code coverage blocks the packaging. (A similar problem exists for packaging 1 patch orgs.)

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: A really good question - we are also heading in this direction (but clearly lower down the curve than you since we're in the foot hills of design). I look forward to seeing the answer to this one!

Comment: To get the same code coverage, you'd have to set up your tests so that they can provide mock classes/interfaces that don't depend on other packages. This is the same technique you'd have to use with a G1MP. Your unit tests should be able to use Dependency Injection or the Stub API to simulate empty placeholders.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox yes we are contemplating that sort of change. Pretty sad to have to write that code though when we already know out code works thanks to the real tests that hit 90% coverage. The mocking work would have roughly the same value add as adding a few thousand lines of `i++;`.

Comment: FYI @PhilW, in case you are thinking about falling back on packaging 1 where you can install the "other" packages in the packaging org, be aware that those are not carried across to patch orgs. So the first time you want to patch, you are stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Just be aware that when using the Stub API, you can’t mock the Static methods.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I'm wondering if this will always be possible to do without adding some "mock" objects in the schema. I did stumble across the "[SObject Fabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator)" solution, but even then it needs an actual object type against which to work.

Comment: @PhilW You could use an object you know exists, like Account, or something?

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes, indeed, though this may not always an option depending on the package's data binding needs (you might need *n* boolean fields on an object, for example, and Account may not have enough). So it looks likely there could be some necessary but unwanted cruft in the package just to get through the coverage threshold...